# Powershell , remove folder with the same name like .zip

Tags: powershell, duplicates, zip, directory

I must delete files which have been extracted from a zip file, into a folder named after the zip file, i.e.:

```
\test1.zip -> \test1
```

My script must find the folder which have the same name as the zip file and delete this folder.

Comment: Do you mean if a folder contains file "TheArchive.zip" and folder "TheArchive" then delete that folder?

Comment: yes, exactly,   For example. In folder c:/temp are files test1.zip, and folder test1. Then delete folder test1, and leave test1.zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get a list of all of the Zip files in the directory, then loop over the results and delete any folder with the same name minus the extension, also known as the `BaseName`.

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.zip | `
  ForEach-Object { if (Test-Path $_.BaseName) {
    Remove-Item -Recurse -Force $_.BaseName }
  }
```

You can enter the entire command on one line, I have split it up so that it is easy to read on here.  I used the following commands in this example:

- [Get-ChildItem](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh849800.aspx) - Creates a object in the pipeline for each file with a `.zip` extension
- [ForEach-Object](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849731.aspx) - Simply allows you to perform an action for each object in the pipeline.
- [Remove-Item](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849765.aspx) - note the use of `-Recurse` and `-Force` ensures that the folder is removed even if it contains files, you **will not** be asked to confirm.

Comment: Thanks, That is what i wont.

Comment: @mino: if this answer resolved your question please consider accepting it as the answer and upvoting it.  This signals to the community and other users that this answer solved your question.